# How I can comment answer in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, comments

I don't want to publish new answer of the question.

I want to ask how I can comments answer.

Can I do it ? or I should have some reputation

Comment: You need 50 reputation in order to comment on _any_ post. You can always comment on your own posts.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the duplicate question.

Comment: @user2320677 You are the OP? If so, why the multiple accounts?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to reach 50 reputation. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment